# Vim - Go to previous location

Tags: vim

Say I open a file in vim. I start on line 1 column 1 and hold down <kbd>j</kbd> until I am on line 14. Pressing <kbd>:</kbd><kbd>7</kbd><kbd>CR</kbd> puts me on line 7. I press <kbd>y</kbd><kbd>y</kbd> to "yank".

How do I return to line 14? Using <kbd>CTRL</kbd> + <kbd>o</kbd> takes me back to the top of the file. <kbd>`</kbd> <kbd>`</kbd> gives me the same results.

Answer (score 119, accepted):

You can type <kbd>7G</kbd> to jump to line#7, then type <kbd>Ctrl-o</kbd> to jump back.
`:set showcmd` to show what you have typed at the right bottom.

---

To yank line#7 (No cursor moving):

```
:7y
```

To paste line#7 below line#14:

```
:7t14
```

Comment: I am loving the `7G` and `''` combo. I even learned `showcmd` as a bonus.

Comment: `Ctrl+o` is really useful, but it's nice to know its opposite: `Ctrl+i`. While `Ctrl+o` takes you "back" in jumplist and `Ctrl+i` takes you "forward". More info at `:help jumplist`

Comment: I found that removing the first line number `:t14` will paste the current line below line#14.

Comment: Ctrl+o insert an new line.

Comment: @towry Please do it in **normal** mode

Answer (score 57):

`<C-o>` and `<C-i>` allow you to go down and up the jumplist. They work with "jump" commands but not with `jjjjjjjjjjj`.

To take advantage of this feature — and save a lot of time and keypresses in the process — I'd advise you to get into the habit of using better ways to navigate through your code : `/?^$fFtTbBeEwW{}` and so on.

And yes, use marks.

Answer (score 37):

One more way: To jump back to another line, you can use <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>'</kbd>. This works similar to an automatic mark, which is set for certain jump movements.

Comment: More precisely you can use  ` ` ( two back ticks ). ' ' will take you to the beginning of the previous line.

Answer (score 26):

Why not [set a mark](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Using_marks) using <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> for example, and then return to it later using <kbd>`</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> or <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>?

Answer (score 12):

Mark the line you were originally on using <kbd>m</kbd><kbd>a</kbd>, then <kbd>'</kbd><kbd>a</kbd> to return there.

Answer (score 3):

If you want to return to a previous location, first you have to mark that location using the mark (m) command, followed by any letter a-z or A-Z, like `ma` to mark a location as 'a'.

To return to that location you would enter `a.